# RewriteRule 500 Error Question

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the following Rewrite Rules set up:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php/api/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php/other/$1 [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately these cause my server to throw a 500 error. Taken individually, they both work fine though.

My intention is that if the request is `http://somesite.com/api/whatever/`, the first rule will get triggered, redirecting to `index.php/api/whatever/`

If anything other than "api" gets sent as the second segment though, it will redirect to `index.php/other/whatever`.

Is my understanding flawed somehow? I thought that it would go down the list, and with the L flag, would stop executing once it hit something. Or is my syntax wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. whenever you get a 500, check `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (or the equivalent path on your system.)
2. I'm pretty sure the hyphen char in your character group is a regex syntax error. (also, the `[NC]` flag makes `[A-Za-z]` redundant

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^api/([-A-Z0-9]+)$ index.php/api/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([-A-Z0-9]+)$ index.php/other/$1 [NC,L]
```

Or perhaps

```
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)$ index.php/api/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php/other/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: +1 To match a hyphen in a character class, it should be the first character after the opening `[` - http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you need [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags), try like that :

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ index.php/api/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/other/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Since no one commented the downvote: [QSA] is used when you modify the Query String and want the original one append to the new one you  defined in the rewrite. There are no query string here (so it's kept unchanged)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But I try these rewrite rules on my local configuration and it work correctly only with QSA flag.